# Google search API multiples input en uno mismo

Tags: php, html, api

Estoy intentando hacer que de diferentes inputs pueda generar una búsqueda en Google, pero Google solo me crea un input pero yo no lo puedo editar.

Código **Javascript**:

```
(function() {
var cx = '010966112395912926010:u_3n5cqxw50';
var gcse = document.createElement('script');
gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
gcse.async = true;
gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

Código **HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="google.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
```

Los inputs van a ser creados por mi.

Por ejemplo:

- Input 1: `intext:"guerra mundial"`
- Input 2: `filetype:ppt`
- Input 3: `intitle:"historia"`

Y que después genere una búsqueda de la siguiente forma en Google, concatenando todo:

```
intext:"guerra mundial" filetype:ppt intitle:"historia"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para implementar una página de resultados de búsqueda independiente, pega el siguiente fragmento de código en su página de resultados:

```
<script>
(function() {
  var cx = 'YOUR_ENGINE_ID';
  var gcse = document.createElement('script');
  gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
  gcse.async = true;
  gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>
<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

Ahora puedes ejecutar la búsqueda en la pagina pasando el parámetro "q" en la URL

```
http://my-results-page-url.com/?q=MisParametrosABuscar
```

Dale un q=MisParametrosABuscar en la barra de direcciones. Esto hace que el elemento  conozca sobre el resultado de la consulta a mostrar.

Lo que debes hacer es concatenar los input y mandar la consulta a la url.

Éxitos con el desarrollo y bendiciones.